# Count tables with the same ID in a column and display the highest

Tags: mysql, sql, count, self-join

I want to show the 5 threads with highest number of posts, but im kinda broken and I cant even imagine how to do it

the SQL tables are like this, of course is just an example

> ```
> id | thread | subject | body
> ________________________________________________________
> 1  | NULL   | Thread1 | this is the body of the first thread id1
> 2  | 1      | NULL    | post id2 in the first thread id1
> 3  | NULL   | Thread2 | this is the body of the 2nd thread id3
> 4  | 2      | NULL    | post id4 in the second thread id4
> 5  | 2      | NULL    | post id4 in the second thread id5
> 6  | NULL   | Thread3 | this is the body of the 3rd thread id6
> 7  | 6      | NULL    | post id4 in the third thread id7
> 8  | 6      | NULL    | post id4 in the third thread id8
> 9  | 6      | NULL    | post id4 in the third thread id9
> ```

I want the result to be like this

> ```
> thread3
> thread2
> thread1
> ```

I should do a separate query?, I mean 2 instead of only one, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to join the table to itself, with the main thread row in the first side of the join and the post rows in the other side:

```
select t1.subject
from mytable t1
join mytable t2 on t2.thread = t1.id
where t1.thread is null
group by 1
order by count(*) desc
limit 5
```

Comment: what you mean with t1 and t2?

Comment: Well, I guess you mean another tables or something, everything is in the same place http://i.imgur.com/EzNwCVM.png (ignore the content, it was just for testing), the first result must be the ID 8(thread 8) with the subject 'qweeqweqwqew', and the second result must be the ID 5(thread 5)

Comment: T1 and t2 are "aliases" for your table (which I simply called mytable because you didn't say what the table name was), needed when joining a table to itself so columns of the different instances of the table can be unambiguously referenced.

Comment: Regarding the output, this query produces exactly the desired output as per the example in your question, which listed the thread names only (no ID column). If you want ID or something else, please edit your question to correct the output you want and leave a message here to let me know you've fixed it and I will change my answer to meet the new requirements.